# How to avoid extra copy of data buffer to string?

Tags: c++

The following is skeleton code for saving multiple pieces of data to `myqueue`. Each chunk of data can be large (say a few MB or more). I have two questions:

- By creating a `string` from a `buf *`, does it involving copying `buf` to new location? is there any performance concern?
- In the `dequeue` function, I am returning `string` as a reference, is this the right way to avoid creating new string?

Thanks.

```
int main() {
   std::queue<std::string> myqueue;
   ... 
   // receive large number
   // data, and enqueue to myqueue
}

void enqueue()
{
   char* buf = (char*)malloc(count);
   myqueue.push(std::string(buf));
   free(buf);
}

std::string& dequeue()
{
   std::string& item = myqueue.front();
   myqueue.pop()
   return item;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By creating a string from a buf *, does it involving copying buf to new location? is there any performance concern?

Yes. It could be. Unless the pattern of usage is clear, it's hard to say whether you need to be concerned.

> In the dequeue function, I am returning string as a reference, is this the right way to avoid creating new string?

No, it is not. You are getting a reference to an object that is not alive when the function returns. Accessing the object through the reference will cause undefined behavior. Be safe and return an object by value.

```
std::string dequeue()
{
   std::string item = myqueue.front();
   myqueue.pop();
   return item;
}
```

Comment: If C++11: `std::string item = std::move(myqueue.front());`

Answer (score 2):

In

```
void enqueue()
{
   char* buf = (char*)malloc(count);
   myqueue.push(std::string(buf));
   free(buf);
}
```

the `std::string(buf)` can't take ownership of `buf` so you are going to have to allocate more memory, copy `buf` into that memory and then put it into the queue.  We can make this better by starting with a `std::string` to begin with.  That would give you something like

```
void enqueue()
{
   myqueue.emplace(count, '\0');
}
```

or if you need to load data into the string

```
void enqueue()
{
    std::string buf(count, '\0');
    load_data(buf.data());
    myqueue.push(std::move(buf));
}
```

In

```
std::string& dequeue()
{
   std::string& item = std::move(myqueue.front());
   myqueue.pop();
   return item;
}
```

you are returning a reference to a local object.  That will lead to undefined behavior because as soon as the function ends the local string is destroyed and you are left with a dangling reference.  TO prevent that you can just return the string by value like

```
std::string dequeue()
{
   std::string item = myqueue.front();
   myqueue.pop();
   return item;
}
```

Comment: Changing `myqueue.push(std::string(count, '\0'))` to `myqueue.emplace(count, '\0')` will save you a move from the temp to the value storage every enqueue. Secondly, in the second example `myqueue.push(std::move(buf));` no move is taking place, you siimply cast `buf` to an rvalue, and then copy it into value storage, per the behavior of the underlying container's `push_back`. Using the `emplace` strategy will actually allow a move construction in value storage. Remember, `move` moves nothing. It is merely an unconditional cast to a `&&`.

Comment: @schulmaster In `myqueue.push(std::move(buf));` `buf` does get moved.  `push is overloaded to take a rvalue reference and will move the parameter into the queue.

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake, it uses move assignment. However, I believe the first criticism I gave remains valid, that using emplace with the string that is truly an rvalue would be more efficient.

Comment: @schulmaster it is and I've edited the answer to use emplace.